# Cloth effect acting strange when I scale the pinning group

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image][image]I have a problem.
I'm kind of new to blender. I'm trying to simulate a curtain and everything works well except when I scale the pinning points in order to get the "waves". Could someone please help me? I would be really grateful! [image: Like here]

Comment: Curtains: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-make-a-curtain/71727#71727 and here with pinning: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98315/how-to-create-a-cloth-stage-valance/98330#98330

Comment: Can you please add more explanation as to what precisely you mean by 'scale the pinning points'. I have just tried this by assigning a set of vertices to a 'pinning' vertex group and then keyframing the horizontal scale of the curtains and this appears to be working fine. Please use the Edit link to add more detail to your question so that we can better understand your specific situation and issue.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! I added 2 more images. There are also clips on youtube, with simulating cloth. The most of them are using this method, scaling the vertices group used for pinning. I'm doing exactly how they are doing and the result is what you see..

Comment: I think I see your problem... Looks like you've scaled the points that are in the pinned group while in edit mode. The problem with this is that you're affecting the geometry of the cloth itself. I'll put together an answer detailing how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

When running a cloth simulation, Blender uses the state of the mesh at the start of the simulation to determine the properties of the cloth - in particular, the size and dimensions of the individual faces. It appears that in your example that you have scaled a set of vertices while in Edit mode and this has affected the dimensions of the cloth itself, rather than just moving those vertices as intended.

In order to resolve this you need to know a little about how the cloth simulation operates. Firstly, the 'base' state of the mesh determines the underlying geometry of the cloth - ie, the vertices of the cloth and the length of any edges connecting those vertices. Once the simulation is started, Blender effectively makes a copy of the entire mesh and moves the location of that copy's vertices based on the simulation - but, importantly, Blender will use the 'actual' mesh edges to limit how far neighbouring vertices can move away from each other - ie, the 'structure' of the cloth. In addition to just the 'distance' between the vertices. Settings in the cloth simulation allow the 'stiffness' of this structure to be set, allowing the cloth to retain it's original shape.

When you 'pin' vertices, you are effectively tying those vertices to the corresponding vertices in the original mesh (rather than the 'copy' that follows the simulation). When you manipulate the original mesh, any 'pinned' vertices will follow where the 'actual' vertex moves. This allows the original mesh to be manipulated to effectively 'drag' the simulated mesh to affect the simulation.

So, to achieve the effect you are looking for, first create the mesh in a form that mimics the actual structure of the cloth - in this case, the curtain is a simple subdivided plane - more subdivisions gives more resolution to the cloth :

[image: cloth mesh]

Select some of the vertices to be 'pinned' - ie, the points where it would be attached to a curtain rail or whatever. Assign those vertices to a vertex group with an appropriate name - eg, 'Pin' :

[image: pinned vertices]

Setup your cloth properties with Pinning enabled, specifying your new 'Pin' vertex group.

Now, simply add a keyframe at the start of the animation to set the scale of the entire mesh to 1.0 and add a second keyframe to reduce the scale of the mesh (in the appropriate dimension - in my case this was in the Y-axis only). Since *only the pinned vertices affect the simulation* it is not necessary to limit the scaling to only the pinned vertices.

[image: curtain mesh scale]

This produces the following result :

[image: final]

Blend file included [image]

Comment: Ok. That is the effect you get on your first set of frames.