# How to create gathered stitches in clothes

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am struggling to mimick the gathered stitches shown in photo here. I have tried stitching two cloth pieces of different lengths. After baking them, it is a failure. 
I had sought Blender tutorials in Youtube, those on gathered stitches. I found none. 
[image]Any suggestion on how to create gathered stitches?

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98315/how-to-create-a-cloth-stage-valance/98330#98330 making Shape Key more random should give you desired result.

Comment: @cgslav, you are brilliant. Thank you very much. 